# memory location of variable using fork

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, fork, ambiguous

I am having difficulty understanding the output of the programe. After using `fork()`, the memory location of the variable `inmem` is showing the same.
Can someone please explain this! 
Thanku

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
int inmem = 9;
int pid = fork();

if(!pid)
{
    printf("child inmem %d %p\n", inmem,&inmem);
    inmem = 8;
    printf("child inmem %d %p\n", inmem, &inmem);

}

else
{
    printf("parent inmem %d %p\n", inmem, &inmem);
    inmem = 5;
    printf("parent inmem %d %p\n", inmem, &inmem);

}
return 0
}
```

OUTPUT-

```
parent inmem 9 0x7ffff0acdfc8
parent inmem 5 0x7ffff0acdfc8
child inmem 9 0x7ffff0acdfc8
child inmem 8 0x7ffff0acdfc8
```

Comment: There are some system calls to *share* virtual memory between several different processes. See [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). You'll need to synchronize, see [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: why have you not included `#include <unistd.h>`?

Comment: Please don't ignore compiler warnings. Compile your code with `-Wall` and note that, for once, you'll see that you need to _cast_ the pointer you're passing to `printf`, to `(void *)`

Comment: Use the flags `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors` in gcc. It will make you write standards-compliant and safe code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `fork()` child will have `separate address space`. This address space refers to the `virtual address space`. So parent and child will have same address that is virtual address.

OS will map this `virtual address` in separate address space with different `physical address`

Answer (score 2):

`fork` creates an exact copy of your process, with regard to your code and adresses. This is already necessary because the code after the fork executes the same way as before and has the same acess to variables. However, once the processes are forked, they no longer are synchronized, so allocating a new memory may yield different addresses.